# How to "use a function" while doing matrix transformation?

Tags: matrix, octave

I have the following code, in Octave:

```
% recode y to Y
I = eye(10);
Y = zeros(5000, 10);
for i=1:5000
  Y(i, :)= I(y(i), :);
end
```

`y` is 5000 x 1 and contains values from 1 to 10
The desired output is Y.
`Y` is 5000 x 10 and contains all 0s except a 1 in the position indicated in the same row of `y`.

I'd like to do this without a loop, for academic purposes; i.e., vectorize it.

A 5000 x 1 * 1 x 10 will give me a 5000 x 10 answer, but the 1 x 10 here needs to change during matrix multiplication for each row to contain all 0s except the position indicated by the "current" row of y.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think your question in better suited for StackOverflow. In any case, just look up `logical indexing`; this will get you the solution you want.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `eye(10)(r,c)` can take a vector for argument `r`, like so:

```
Y = eye(10)(y,:)
```

I discovered this through trial and error just now. It looks like it gives the right answer and it doesn't need a loop. It's much simpler and hopefully faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using of "chain indexing" a(..)(...) is an Octave addition (not available in Matlab) and has nothing to do with "use a function while doing matrix multiplication"

Anyway, you should use a sparse matrix for creation and storage:

```
c = 5e3;
r = 10;
y = randi (c, r, 1);

## Answer from toddmo
tic
Y = eye(c)(y,:);
toc

## Answer from Andy
tic
Y2 = sparse (1:r, y, 1, r, c);
toc

## Ensure, that they are equal
assert (Y, full (Y2));

## check the size in memory
whos
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 0.0635939 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000108957 seconds.
Variables in the current scope:

Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
    Y          10x5000                  400000  double
    Y2         10x5000                   40168  double
    ans         5x10                       400  double
    c           1x1                          8  double
    r           1x1                          8  double
    y          10x1                         80  double

Total is 100062 elements using 440664 bytes
```

As you can see the speedup factor is > 500 and the memory usage only a tenth... You can use the sparse matrix in almost any computation as you would to use a full matrix. Use `full` to convert it if you really need to

Comment: As to your initial statement, I meant "use a function while doing matrix transformation". The feature that my answer uses, which you call chain indexing, is a function in the algorithmic sense; to wit, it is a lookup function. I corrected my title.

Comment: I don't understand `sparse`. What it does, what the arguments are or how they are related or used by the function. Not by just looking at your answer, anyway. You have also inverted the normal meaning of `r` (row) and `c` column. `5e3` anti-clarifies things. If my answer is eye(10), then your calling it wrong with `eye(5000)`.

Comment: You are right, I've switched the number of rows and columns in my answer. 5e3 is scientific notation for 5000 (okay?). A sparse matrix doesn't store the zeros (which are 90% in your case).